# How do I relate data without one single master or starting point

Tags: python, postgresql, database-design, sqlalchemy, relationship

I have a set of "people" data that contains identity numbers. This data comes from various sources in a format like below

```
Source1: IDNumber:I1, Passport:P1,SocialSecurity:S1,DateOfBirth,13/03/1967
Source2: Passport:P1,VATNumber:V1,marital_status,Married
Source3: TaxNumber:T1,IDNumber:I1,HasPaidTax,True
```

The assumption is that numbers supplied in the same row are related. So from the set above, we are allowed to make the following assumptions: 
I1 is related to P1, S1, V1, T1 meaning all those identities belong to one person and hence the data that was supplied in the three instances i.e. DateOfBirth, MaritalStatus, HasPaidTax all belong to one person.

Currently, all this different IDTypes go into one table:

```
PID=======IDTYpe=======IDNumber
 1---------IDNumber-----I1
 2---------Passport-----P1
 3---------VATNumber----V1
 etc
```

Question is, how do I store the related nature of this ID Numbers in a database? From my searches, I have come across [adjacency list model and nested set models](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/). This however, are for storing hierarchical information. In my case, nothing really is the parent or child of the other. Its not a family tree. Its just numbers that are related to each other horizontally. No one ID Type is the Master ID

Am using python, postgresql and SQLAlchemy as the ORM which has some [nested](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/browser/examples/nested_sets/nested_sets.py) functionality with it though am still not sure if what I have here can be represented hierarchically...

Comment: What about table with one (artificial sequence) primary key and then pointers to other tables (Source1, Source2, Source3)? e.g. table: `id_party (PK), IDNumber (FK), Passport (FK), VATNumber (FK)`? Then `IDNumber` is primary key in `Source1`, `Passport` is primary key in `Source2`  etc..

Comment: By Artificial Sequence you mean the AutoIncrement from the database for primary keys? That said, there are no `source_tables`. The source of the data is XML and/or flat files. When all the data comes in, I put the Identity Numbers in one table as shown above with the IDType and the IDNumber. Ideally I want it to remain with that one table and maybe another one just showing the relationship. Hope I've answered else please elaborate on your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've finally got a solution that works for my question... I'll show here how to store relations in two ways. Using Nested Set Model in a relational database and using a Key-value based solution with persistence

## Solution 1: Pull your hair code: Nested Set Model

```
CREATE TABLE identity
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  identity_type_id integer NOT NULL,
  "number" character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT identity_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT identity_identity_type_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (identity_type_id)
      REFERENCES config_identity_type (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT identity_1 UNIQUE (identity_type_id, number)
)

CREATE TABLE identity_related
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  identity_id integer NOT NULL,
  is_processed boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  ref_no character varying(20) NOT NULL,
  lft integer,
  rgt integer,
  CONSTRAINT identity_related_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT identity_related_identity_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (identity_id)
      REFERENCES identity (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

For each row I purse through, I grab all the identity numbers on that row, generate a unique reference number then using the nested set model, I set the respective left and right values into the identity_related. It worked.

The only challenge which is pointed out with the nested set model is that updating a set is punitive. In my case, I needed to check that each idnumber had been saved, get the IDs it was saved with, and with the later, also check the idnumbers they had been saved with and the loop continues till the end....

Once am done iterating, I generate a new reference number and set all the fetched IDs lft & rgt. The query worked. But for about 1 million entries of identity_related, this query took 5 days but only because I killed it on the 5th day and by then, it had done about 700,000 IDs.

The code looked like this:

```
def relate_identities(self, is_processed):
    #http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/
    #http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/
    #http://www.pure-performance.com/2009/03/managing-hierarchical-data-in-sql/
    #http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/browser/examples/nested_sets/nested_sets.py
    identify = Identity()
    session = Session()
    entries = []
    related = []
    tbl = IdentityRelated
    not_processed = False
    log_counter = 0
    id_counter = 0
    while True:
        #Get the initial record
        identity = session.query(tbl).filter(tbl.is_processed == is_processed).order_by(tbl.id).first()
        entries.append({identity:'not_processed'})
        related.append(identity)
        if len(entries) == 0: break
        #for key, value in entries[0].items():
            #print("ID:%s; ref_no:%s" %(key.id, key.ref_no))
        while True:
            for entry in entries:
                if not_processed == True: break
                for key, value in entry.items():
                    if value == 'not_processed':
                        not_processed = True
                        break
                    
            if not_processed == False: 
                break
            else:
                not_processed = False
            
            for entry in entries:
                for key, value in entry.items():
                    if value == 'not_processed': 
                        #Get objects which have the same identity_id as current object
                        duplicates = session.query(tbl).filter(tbl.identity_id == key.id).\
                                                            order_by(tbl.id).all()  
                        if len(duplicates) != 0: 
                            for duplicate in duplicates:
                                if not duplicate in related:
                                    related.append(duplicate)
                                    entries.append({duplicate:'not_processed'})
    
                        for entry in entries:
                            for key, value in entry.items():
                                if value == 'not_processed': 
                                    #Get objects that have the same reference numbers as all entries that we have fetched so far
                                    ref_nos = session.query(tbl).filter(tbl.ref_no == key.ref_no).order_by(tbl.id).all()
                                    for ref_no in ref_nos:
                                        if not ref_no in related:
                                            related.append(ref_no)
                                            entries.append({ref_no:'not_processed'})
                                    #Remove current entry from entries
                                    entries.remove(entry)
                                    #Add the entry but change the status
                                    entries.append({key:'processed'})
                    
        #Generate a new RelationCode
        while True:
            ref_no = get_reference_no(REFERENCE_NO.idrelation)
            params = {'key':'relation','relation':ref_no}
            if identify.get_identity(session, **params) == None:
                break             
        #Add each relatedID to the DB and set the Nested Set Value
        #Set is_processed as True to ensure we don't run it again
        relation_counter = 0
        for entry in entries:
            for key, value in entry.items():
                key.ref_no = ref_no
                key.lft = relation_counter + 1
                key.rgt = ((len(related) * 2) - relation_counter)
                key.is_processed = True
                relation_counter += 1  
    
        #Reset values
        log_counter += 1
        id_counter += 1
        related = []
        entries = []
            
        #Commit the session
        session.commit()
```

Even if this code was optimized and became faster, querying for the related IDs involved fetching the ID that I want, getting the associated reference number and then calling an SQL `distinct` search against that reference number for me to get the distinct idnumbers related to that identity.

## Solution 2: 3 lines of code: NoSQL - Redis Key:Value Sets

Back to the drawing board i.e. Google. Did a search of "storing related identiy numbers" yeah, I was that desparate... I got an instagram engineering to the article [Storing hundreds of millions of simple key-value pairs in Redis](http://tinyurl.com/cjkb6rr). Lets say [Redis](http://redis.io) is my new best friend especially since it took me 10 minutes to read the intro, 5 minutes to do the installation and 40 minutes to go through 3 basic tutorials. After that it took me 3 hrs of actually solving my problem and with Redis it basically means trying to figure out the most efficient way to store my key:value pairs for my identity numbers. Now I think I have solved it using **[Redis Sets](http://redis.io/topics/data-types)** in 4 lines of code.

After fetching say three identity numbers that have been submitted together, I create a list called relation. With Redis `Sets`, you cannot have duplicate values so even if my three identity numbers are submitted multiple times, the length of my set will never grow and I won't have duplicates like I did with the relation database above. If an extra 4th ID is added, then my set grows by 1. Importantly, with the same number of identities, this code took 2hrs 23 minutes and total memory consumption was: 'used_memory_peak_human': '143.11M'

```
for related_outer in relation:
    #Create a set using the ID_Number as the key, and the other ID numbers as the values
    for related_inner in relation:
        redis_db.sadd(related_outer.number, related_inner.number)
```

My new best friend. Redis....

I welcome info to improve the above or a totally new way of storing the relations.

Answer (score 0):

Create a second table `Person` that stores just primary keys:

```
class Person(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    idtentiy_numbers = relationship("IdentityNumber", backref="person")

class IdentityNumber(Base):
    ...
    person_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("person.id")
```

The basic idea here is that you would store an ID to group by. The above one is a clean solution because it also contains a list of available IDs. You could also make this in a single table, by not making `person_id` a foreign key: Then it would only contain an arbitrary number, e.g. 1, 2, 3, ...

In any way you could find out the data belonging together by finding out what the `person_id` is and grouping by it.

Comment: I used your example and created a nested set model... then it became too complicated to upate. I then rewrote it using Redis. I've posted an answer. Thanks.